# How to add onClickListener on images in recyclerView?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclick

I am trying to attach onclick listener on images in this code, using Glide framework but I'm not able to find a solution for that. Can someone help with this?

Images are showing in emulator already.

Thanks in advance

```
package com.example.andoridlifecycle.adapters

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy
import com.example.andoridlifecycle.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_custom_row.view.*

class ItemAdapter(private val context: Context, private val urls: ArrayList<String>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    /**
     * Inflates the custom view which is designed in xml layout file
     */
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_custom_row,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }


    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Array with urls
        val url = urls[position]

        Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(holder.imageView)
    }

    // Gets the number of items in the list
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return urls.size
    }
     // A ViewHolder describes an item view and metadata about its place within the RecyclerView.

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {

        val imageView: ImageView = view.iv_image
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm Java Developer so I cannot code with Kotlin but I'll show you how to set `OnClickListener` on your `imageView`. For using OnclickListener on imageView no need for Glide Library.
Just add the below lines in your onBindViewHolder

```
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "this is number: "+position+" Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // or your code for imageView
        });
```

Your new code looks like the below:-

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // Array with urls
        val url = urls[position]

//code for onClick on image
holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Toast.makeText(context, "this is number: "+position+" Image Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // or your code for imageView
        });


        Glide.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .into(holder.imageView)
    }
```

Make sure to change `JAVA` to `Kotlin` in my code. If you any problem is causing, Let me know